# Positive definite matrix and self-adjoint invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix in $\mathbb{C}$. Can a self-adjoint
>   and invertible matrix $E$ be found such that $A=E^2$?

The converse is true iirc, that is, given a self-adjoint invertible matrix $E$ in the complex field, its square is positive definite. But how about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If $A=E^2$, with $E^H=E$ ($E^H$ denotes the hermitian transpose), then
$$
A^H=(E^2)^H=(E^H)^2=E^2=A
$$
so also $A$ is self-adjoint. If $E$ is invertible, then also $A=E^2$ is invertible. Moreover $A$ is positive definite, because
$$
x^HAx=x^HE^HEx=(Ex)^H(Ex)>0
$$
for $x\ne0$, since $Ex\ne0$ as $E$ is invertible.

Is the condition that $A$ is self-adjoint and positive definite sufficient for writing it as $A=E^2$? Yes. $A$ is normal and so diagonalizable by means of a unitary matrix:
$$
A=U^HDU
$$
where $U^H=U^{-1}$ and $D$ is diagonal. The eigenvalues of $D$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $A$, so they are positive real numbers. Therefore we can write $D=D_1^2$ where we choose in each diagonal place the positive square root of the corresponding coefficient in $D$.

Now, set $E=U^HD_1U$. Then $E^H=E$ and $A=E^2$.